# How to set multiple types for generic values in Go correctly?

Tags: go, generics, containers

I want to set multiple types for values of hashmap in Golang. I implemented golang generics `any`, and wrote function that returned `map[string]any`.

However, after I ran the code, it returned

```
$ cannot use r.Method (variable of type string) as type T in map literal
```

What is the correct way of setting multiple types for values of hashmap in Go?

Here's my code

```
package main

type RequestProperty struct {
    Method string
    Params []any
    Id     int
}

func SetRequestProperty[T any](payloadCombine bool) map[string]T {
    var p map[string]T
    var r = RequestProperty{
        Method: "SET_PROPERTY",
        Params: []any{"combined", payloadCombine},
        Id:     5,
    }
    // just for test
    p = map[string]T{
        "method": r.Method,  // << Error Here
    }

    return p
}

func main() {
    p := SetRequestProperty(true)
}
```

[EDIT]
This seems to be working though... I don't know why.

```
package main

type RequestProperty struct {
    Method string
    Params []any
    Id     int
}

// delete [T any], map[string]T 
// change it to map[string]any
func SetRequestProperty(payloadCombine bool) map[string]any {
    var p map[string]any
    var r = RequestProperty{
        Method: "SET_PROPERTY",
        Params: []any{"combined", payloadCombine},
        Id:     5,
    }
    // just for test
    p = map[string]any{
        "method": r.Method,
    }

    return p
}

func main() {
    p := SetRequestProperty(true)
}
```

Shouldn't `T` just act like an alias to type any? Am I misunderstanding something?

Comment: Note the error you are getting is a build error, not a runtime error.

Comment: @Dave OK. Thanks! I changed my return value to map[string]any and deleted [T any] and the code seems to be working. But please may I ask why? I don't know why it worked out this way.

Comment: @RedBlue you mean that stating [T any] does not make T an alias for any in the function scope?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Shouldn't T just act like an alias to type any?

### No, it shouldn't.

`T` is a type parameter, not `any`. It is only ***constrained*** by `any`.

More generally: a type parameter is not its constraint.

Each time a generic function is instantiated, `T` is assigned a concrete type argument — which satisfies its constraint — and within the function body, `map[string]T` becomes a map from `string` to whatever the concrete `T` is.

```
p := SetRequestProperty[int](true)
// makes body look like: `var p map[string]int`
// the literal `map[string]int{"method": r.Method}` obviously can't work
```

Therefore at compile time, the compiler will reject assignments to `T` that are not compatible with **all** types in `T`'s type set. The code `map[string]T{"method": r.Method}` doesn't compile because:

- `T` is constrained by `any`, so its type set comprises anything
- `r.Method` is of type `string`, and `string` isn't assignable to anything.

---

With `map[string]any` instead **`any` is not used as a constraint, it is used as a static type**, which is an alias of `interface{}` and all types are always assignable to the empty interface.

If you want to have [a container with different runtime types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69485180/go-generic-container-with-different-runtime-types), using `any` as a static type as in `map[string]any` is the only way. To restrict allowed types, use basic interfaces instead of type parameters.

See also the top-voted answer here: [What are the benefits of replacing an interface argument with a type parameter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71887083/what-are-the-benefits-of-replacing-an-interface-argument-with-a-type-parameter)